# How does java.util.Collections.reverse() work?

Tags: java, collections, methods, static

See the documentation of [java.util.Collections.reverse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29).

I don't understand how Java methods can only pass by value, but yet the following is allowed:

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list)
```

How can it change the original object passed through the parameter? Especially when all objects passed through parameters are passed by value? Shouldn't that mean that only a copy of the object is passed through, and therefore only a reference could be returned? Since we're returning void, how can we change the original object being passed through?

- A very confused Java Padawan

Comment: Have a look at its [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.reverse%28java.util.List%29)!

Comment: You are passing a reference by value.

Answer (score 10):

The *reference* to the list is passed by value.

Both the caller and the `reverse()` method have a reference to the same list.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Andy's answer:

You pass the value of reference to the list and you cannot change the original reference. This is to demonstrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1);
    test(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}

public static void test(List<?> list) {
    list = Arrays.asList(2,2,2);
}
```

it still prints [1, 1, 1] though we assigned [2, 2, 2] in test method to list

Answer (score 0):

> How can it change the original object passed through the parameter?

You pass a reference, you can't pass an object.

> Especially when all objects passed through parameters are passed by value?

References are passed by value, not objects.

> Shouldn't that mean that only a copy of the object is passed through,

Only a copy of the reference is passed through.

> and therefore only a reference could be returned?

A reference is the only thing not returned.

> Since we're returning void, how can we change the original object being passed through?

You can't change the reference, but you can change what the reference points to.